# How come my loop doesn't break?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This is a simplified version of my actual code. I would expect the outer loop to break after 7 loops and the inner one to break after five, but neither one does.

```
var f = 0;
for (var i = 0; 7; i++) {
    console.log('I:', i)
    f++
    for (var x = f+1; 5; x++) {
        console.log('X:', x)
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {` and `for (var x = f+1; x < 5 ; x++) {`

Comment: @thefourtheye "Avoid answering questions in comments"

Comment: Can I somehow see the close-reasons?

Comment: @KristofferNolgren Questions requiring just some trivial syntax fix get closed as such, because they have close to no value for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`5` is an expression that doesn't do anything. The loop needs a Boolean expression that will be true of false -- `5` is always true. You need to check if `i < 5`.

```
var f = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    console.log('I:', i)
    f++
    for (var x = f+1; i < 5; x++) {
        console.log('X:', x)
    }
}
```

Comment: `5 is an expression that doesn't do anything` - Not true. It is truthy and so the loop never breaks.